# Pioneer TV shows "unsupported" when connected to RPI 4

Tags: boot, pi-4, hdmi

When I connect my 2GB RAM Raspberry Pi 4 (running 64-bit Ubuntu-Mate 20.04) to my Pioneer LED-42K200D, the TV shows "unsupported", which I infer as referring to the signal format. I've tried various configurations in config.txt, and nothing work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That TV model, and some model from the same and other vendors have the option to select between HDMI/DVI/Auto-detect mode, which corresponds to CEA (Consumer Electronics Association) and DMT (Display Monitor Timings) HDMI groups `hdmi_group` in [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md).

If your TV is in Auto-detect mode, it may confuse the signal sent from the Pi. Set the TV to DVI and configure the Pi to DMT (or TV to HDMI and Pi to CEA if you want sound) to fix it.

Comment: I would recommend HDMI/CEA over DVI/DMT

Comment: @JaromandaX that's a nice idea, but I was thinking DVI/DMT mode could save me from configuring overscan if I'm wearing a headphone.